# How manage results from mysql properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling an array out one column of data from my larger MySQL table and the data could look like the following:

```
apple; banana; peach; blue paper
peach; apple; car; truck; pen; computer; pencil; marker
computer
examples; etc
more; materials;
```

When I take that output I am trying to write PHP code that puts it into an HTML select box, that is every *unique* value. For example I do not need to see apple twice or computers, I want the dropdown list to look like this:

```
apple
banana
peach
blue paper
car
truck
etc...
```

Here is my PHP code. I can't figure out how to take the output and split it apart and make it unique and separate again. My assumption is that I have to take `$rowmod` and run some sort of while loop on it.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($productlist))
{ 
    $rowmod = strtr($row['product']," ","_");
    $rowmod = strtr($row['product'],"; ", "\n");
    echo "<option value='$rowmod'>$rowmod</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up the products list first, remove the duplicates, then spit out the `<option>`s in a second loop.

```
$products = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($productlist))
{
    $names    = explode('; ', $row['product']);
    $products = array_merge($products, $names);
}

$products = array_unique($products);

foreach ($products as $product)
{
    echo "<option value='$product'>$product</option>";
}
```

Comment: OMG that worked perfectly. I really don't understand what you did but it worked. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Added comments for @user2429563, Make sure to +1 for good answer!